# Notice ''Too many URLs ''

Tags: url, google-analytics, notice

I get notice in my google analytics panel:

Too many URLs

The number of unique URLs for owner review All site data exceeds the daily limit. Excess data is displayed in the summary row (left) in the reports.

Google Analytics summarizes data when too many rows in a table in one day. When you send too many unique URLs, surplus value summary is displayed in a single line reports the value (left) for the URL. This severely slows down your ability to perform detailed analysis of the URL.

Too many URLs are usually the result of a combination of a number of unique URL parameters. To avoid surpassing the limitations, the typical solution could be the exclusion of irrelevant parameters from URLs. For example, open the section Administator> Settings ownership review and use the setting Excluding query parameters in the URL to exclude parameters such as sessionid and vision. If your site supports a site search, use the Search Settings sites to track the parameters related to the search while at the same time removes from URLs

How this will affect on my website ?
I not understand why i get this error and how to fix this ?

I check this what google suggest:

Administator> Settings ownership review and use the setting Excluding query parameters in the URL to exclude parameters such as sessionid and vision.

Can anyone explain me how to use this for fix problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not affect your website, is affects the GA reports only.

The url for any pageview is stored in the "page" dimension. [Google Analytics can display at maximum 50 000 distinct values](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009671?hl=en) for this dimension for the selected  timeframe. In your case there are more than 50 000 values, so any excess pages will be grouped together in a row labeled "other".

Now it may be that you have more than 50 000 distinct urls in your website, but Google thinks that this is unlikely, so it suggests to check if you are "artifically" inflating the number of distinct values for the page dimensions.

A bad but simple example: Imagine you allow your users to choose their own background color for your site, and that the choice of color was transmitted in an query parameter. So you might have e.g.

index.php?bgcolor=#cc0000
index.php?bgcolor=#ee5500
index.php?bgcolor=#000000
....

Due to the query parameter these urls would show up as three different pages, i.e. three different rows in the Google Analytics reports, despite the fact that in all cases the same content is displayed (albeit with different background colors).

The proper strategy in this case would be to go to the admin section, view settings, and in the "ignore url parameters" box insert the bgcolor parameter (and all other parameters  that do not change the content that is display). Now the parameter will be stripped from the url before the data is processed, and the pageview will be aggregated into a single row with index.php as single value for the page dimension (of course you have to insert your own query parameter names).

Comment: thanks for fast answer :) this is what i understand, please check photo http://s2.postimg.org/3vecis3eh/here.png there section admin - view settings i need to enter some part of my
website who have same content e.g. in my case domain.com open same content like domain.com/new
and there i will add just ''new'' and this will google in future read like same page like domain.com ? and i fix problem ?

Comment: did you resolve this problem because it's affect my website, plz any help